# Is there a way to find the index of a element randomly grabed from an array?

Tags: javascript

Quick beginner question here, I was just wordering if there is a better way of doing this. Im trying to get a random element from an array and also find out the index of the element at the same time.

So far: `let randBaseIndex = dna[Math.floor(Math.random() *dna.length)];`

This will grab will a random element from the array [dna] and show me its value, but how can i get the values index? I have tried to use .findIndex and .IndexOf but since the array repeats values it only gets the first value that matches not the exact index of the element it randomly chose.

I do have a sort of work-around, by first putting the random number in a placeholder value and then doing dna[placeholder], so therefore the placeholder value is my index value. I was just wondering what else one could do.

Comment: Why not just do it in two lines?

Comment: More specifically, `let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * dna.length); let randBaseIndex = dna[index];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: I would do this in two lines rather than one. This is perfectly readable:

```js
// note this is not 100% uniform - I assume that's fine
const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * dna.length);
const element = dna[index];
```

If you for some reason have "do it in one line" as a requirement there are plenty of hacks possible such as using an anonymous function:

```js
const [element, index] = (i => [dna[i], i])(Math.floor(Math.random() * dna.length));
```

Comment: Well if the two line soulution is perfectly acceptable then i suppose that is what my placeholder solution was, so thats good :) and i learned something from the one line example, tyvm

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: I made a misleading. Fixed now. Before the **getBasedIndex** wasn't a pure function, now it's.

Should be a lot of ways to get it. This is a simple way.

```js
const dna = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T']



function getBasedIndex(arr) {
  let item = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() *arr.length)];
  let index = arr.indexOf(item);
  return { item, index };
}

console.log(getBasedIndex(dna))
```

Comment: What a shame, I made a mistake, sorry. Thanks for notifying me. Now we have a pure function without external dependencies.